# Browser not caching JSON output, but is HTML output - Symfony2

Tags: php, caching, symfony, http-headers

This must be so simple, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I'm using Symfony2 but I suppose that's not the issue.

(1) Using this (example) my HTML output pages are cached perfectly by a browser:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=60, private
```

...but then if I output in JSON and use exactly the same cache headers, the browser won't cache it.

(2) If I use this:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=60, public
```

...then the Symfony reverse-proxy kicks in and works great (for both HTML and JSON), so it is definitely the browser not caching JSON that's the problem.

I've looked at Apache settings, but all I can see are ones that will set cache headers that I'm already using (e.g. ExpiresDefault).

Comment: Make sure you don't have cache busting enabled on the ajax library that you are using. I.e in jQuery it would be `cache:false` in the getJSON/ajax/get call

Comment: Actually I'm just doing it in a web browser by returning a JSON and using the application/json header so it can't be this, but thanks.